# Getting error while trying to run application in play framework

Tags: java, playframework

I am new to play framework.I am trying to run an application like this

```
$ play eclipse
Error during sbt execution: Could not find configuration file 'd:/play/framework
/sbt/sbt.boot.properties'.  Searched:
        file:/c:/Users/Alok/test-app/
        file:/C:/Users/Alok/
        file:/D:/play/framework/sbt/
```

I searched a lot and got some solution but it is not working.I am using play version 2.2.1

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer but... personally I would stick to play v. 2.1.x since 2.2.x is still unstable and has sbt build system.

Comment: @dstronczak [`2.2.1`](http://www.playframework.com/download) is the latest stable release so I don't know what you mean when you are saying that `2.2.x` is unstable.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Beach linked to the answer, but it is better to have the explanation directly here:

Play cannot be run from the Git shell so in case you're using it (I was) you've got to switch to the standard Windows command line.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this discussion on the play-framework Google Group:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/CN0L5AaBxwg/discussion